# active styles on button is not getting applied when button is focused

Tags: html, css

I have selector like
button:hover:active::before{
content: "",
// button active overlay styles
}

This works when that particular button is not focused but when I use tab key and get my focus on button hover styles is getting applied but active state styles is not working

Just for information my hover selector is like this

button:hover::before{

content: "",

// button hover overlay styles

}

So I don't know why it is not working

I want that active state styles should get applied even when button is focused

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] which includes the relevant HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without better example of your code... As far as I know CSS syntax doesn't support 2 pseudo-classes to be chained
that's the `:hover` and `:active` together. One thing you could try is to split your css to two parts:

```css
button:active::before {
    /** your properties here */
}
button:hover::before {
    /** your properties here */
}
```